# Jquery contextmenu calling a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I want to call a function inside a context menu. I tried working on buttons and it perfectly works. When I tried to place in context menu I can't call the function. I used this library https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu for the context menu.

My table:

```
<table id="ppmpsupplies" class="table table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Code</th>
                  <th>General Description</th>
                  <th>Unit</th>
                  <th>Quantity</th>
                  <th>Estimated Budget</th>
                  <th>Mode of Procurement</th>
                  <th>Actions</th>

                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php foreach($items as $item){?>
                <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $item->id;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $item->description;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $item->unit;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $item->quantity;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $item->budget;?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $item->mode;?></td>                     
              </tr>
              <?php }?>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td>Total</td>
              <td></td>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
```

My context menu:

```
"edit": {
        name: "Edit",
        icon: "fa-pencil-square-o",
        callback: function(item, id) {
        $('#gcjmodal').on('click', edit_item('$item->id'));
        // $('#gcjmodal').click(edit_item('$item->id'));
        return true;
        }
        },
"delete": {
        name: "Delete",
        icon: "fa-trash-o",
        callback: function(item, id) {
        //$(this).delete_item('$item->id');
        // $(this).on('click', delete_item('$item->id'));
        return true;
        }
        },
```

My function:

```
    function edit_item(id) {
        save_method = 'update';
        $('#gcjform')[0].reset();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo site_url('ppmp/ajax_edit/')?>" + id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {

                $('[name="id"]').val(data.id);
                $('[name="description"]').val(data.description);
                $('[name="unit"]').val(data.unit);
                $('[name="quantity"]').val(data.quantity);
                $('[name="budget"]').val(data.budget);
                $('[name="mode"]').val(data.mode);

                $('#gcjmodal').iziModal('open');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error get data from ajax');
            }
        });
    }
function delete_item(id) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure delete this data?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo site_url('ppmp/delete_item')?>/" + id,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error deleting data');
                }
            });
```

Comment: what is `gcjmodal`? will this be available while calling context menu, i am asking this because inside context menu callback you are attaching click event handler to `gcjmodal`.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, its a modal from the plugin iziModal. When I try to edit/delete this is the error. `POST http://localhost/csc/ppmp/delete_item/$item-%3Eid 400 (Bad Request)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line of code is

```
$('#gcjmodal').on('click', edit_item('$item->id'));
```

as you're passing a string to the `edit_item` function (i.e. `'$item->id'`).

You need to parse that with PHP tags. So the line should be:

```
$('#gcjmodal').on('click', edit_item('<?php print $item->id ?>'));
```

Comment: ,that's the missing piece of code. You got it right sir. Thanks for helping

Comment: Sir when I try to edit. The last row of data has been fetched. I want to select other rows of data.

Comment: `$item` will always reference the last element in the array. You'll need to dynamically pass the ID of each row into the edit_item() function.

Comment: Can you use `item` or `id` found within the callback closure? `callback: function(item, id) {` - so your code would be `$('#gcjmodal').on('click', edit_item(id));`

Comment: This is my new line of code `callback: function(item, id) { $('#ppmpsupplies tr').on('click', edit_item(id)); return true; }`... I call on **tableID** then **tr** to be exact.

Comment: What's the value of the id / item that's passed to the closure? Do they contain the ID of the row you want to edit?

Comment: No sir . Still the last element of the array when I check on the developers tool in the browser. Still the word **id**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147473/discussion-between-steadweb-and-larigyn).